# AUCTeX, preview-latex, and Ghostscript (Emacs)

Tags: emacs, auctex, preview, ghostscript

I'll keep this short and sweet; Emacs can't find `gs`, which has been installed via *brew* and works fine.

**Error**
`PDF2DSC sentinel: Searching for program: No such file or directory, gs`

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a test.  $x^4$.
\end{document}
```

And my `PATH` after init: `"/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/local:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"`

`brew` placed a symlink to Ghostscript under `/usr/local/bin` `->` `/usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.06/bin/gs`.  (Adding this directory doesn't help.)

---

Is this a problem with `preview` in some way, or is it a problem with Emacs itself?  (I should note that running the shell command directly (`M-! gs`) works as expected, and running `psf2dsc` manually also seems to work as expected (no errors, `mwe.dsc` produced).)

---

Per @Charles' request, `echo $PATH` produces `/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/local:/usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.06/bin:/u‌​sr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` under `M-x eshell`.

---

Per @Charles' request, `M-x preview-report-bug` produces

```
Emacs  : GNU Emacs 24.2.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.36)
 of 2012-08-27 on bob.porkrind.org
Package: 11.86

current state:
==============
(setq
 AUCTeX-version "11.86"
 LaTeX-command-style '(("" "%(PDF)%(latex) %S%(PDFout)"))
 image-types '(png gif tiff jpeg xpm xbm pbm)
 preview-image-type 'png
 preview-image-creators '((dvipng
               (open preview-gs-open preview-dvipng-process-setup)
               (place preview-gs-place)
               (close preview-dvipng-close))
              (png (open preview-gs-open) (place preview-gs-place)
               (close preview-gs-close))
              (jpeg (open preview-gs-open)
               (place preview-gs-place) (close preview-gs-close))
              (pnm (open preview-gs-open) (place preview-gs-place)
               (close preview-gs-close))
              (tiff (open preview-gs-open)
               (place preview-gs-place) (close preview-gs-close))
              )
 preview-dvipng-image-type 'png
 preview-dvipng-command "dvipng -picky -noghostscript %d -o \"%m/prev%%03d.png\""
 preview-pdf2dsc-command "pdf2dsc %s.pdf %m/preview.dsc"
 preview-gs-command "gs"
 preview-gs-options '("-q" "-dSAFER" "-dNOPAUSE" "-DNOPLATFONTS" "-dPrinted"
              "-dTextAlphaBits=4" "-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4")
 preview-gs-image-type-alist '((png png "-sDEVICE=png16m")
                   (dvipng png "-sDEVICE=png16m")
                   (jpeg jpeg "-sDEVICE=jpeg")
                   (pnm pbm "-sDEVICE=pnmraw")
                   (tiff tiff "-sDEVICE=tiff12nc"))
 preview-fast-conversion t
 preview-prefer-TeX-bb nil
 preview-dvips-command "dvips -Pwww -i -E %d -o %m/preview.000"
 preview-fast-dvips-command "dvips -Pwww %d -o %m/preview.ps"
 preview-scale-function 'preview-scale-from-face
 preview-LaTeX-command '("%`%l \"\\nonstopmode\\nofiles\\PassOptionsToPackage{"
             ("," . preview-required-option-list)
             "}{preview}\\AtBeginDocument{\\ifx\\ifPreview\\undefined" preview-default-preamble "\\fi}\"%' %t")
 preview-required-option-list '("active" "tightpage" "auctex"
                (preview-preserve-counters "counters"))
 preview-preserve-counters nil
 preview-default-option-list '("displaymath" "floats" "graphics" "textmath"
                   "sections" "footnotes")
 preview-default-preamble '("\\RequirePackage["
                ("," . preview-default-option-list)
                "]{preview}[2004/11/05]")
 preview-LaTeX-command-replacements nil
 preview-dump-replacements '(preview-LaTeX-command-replacements
                 ("\\`\\([^ ]+\\)\\(\\( +-\\([^ \\\\\"]\\|\\\\\\.\\|\"[^\"]*\"\\)*\\)*\\)\\(.*\\)\\'" "\\1 -ini -interaction=nonstopmode \"&\\1\" " preview-format-name ".ini \\5")
                 )
 preview-undump-replacements '(("\\`\\([^ ]+\\) .*? \"\\\\input\" \\(.*\\)\\'"
                "\\1 -interaction=nonstopmode \"&"
                preview-format-name "\" \\2")
                   )
 preview-auto-cache-preamble 'ask
 preview-TeX-style-dir "/Users/sean/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.86/latex"
 )

Output from running `gs -h':
```

Followed by a message: `Searching for program: No such file or directory, gs`

Comment: I should add that I'm trying to emulate Aquamacs' behavior - it's prepackaged with AucTeX, but too bloated for my taste. `preview-latex` works fine under it.

Comment: Could you run eshell (`M-x eshell`) in an instance of Emacs, and say what result you get from `echo $PATH`?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/local:/usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.06/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: I might have a few questions.  The next is, after getting this error, can you run `M-x preview-report-bug RET`, and paste the results (which might be quite long) into your question?

Comment: @CharlesStewart, done.

Comment: That all looks correct (though there isn't actually any error reported there), so I'm fishing here.  Maybe `exec-path` somehow doesn't contain a bin directory even though it is in emacs' PATH: can you tell me what you get from `C-h v exec-path RET`?

Comment: I'll be damned.  `("/usr/bin" "/bin" "/usr/sbin" "/sbin" "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin")` from the Emacs app and `("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin" "/usr/local/bin" "/usr/bin" "/bin" "/usr/sbin" "/sbin" "/usr/X11/bin" "/usr/local/git/bin" "/usr/texbin" "/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.2/libexec/emacs/24.2/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2")`.  Terminal can't do it anyways; "Display geometry unavailable: Wrong type argument: `number-ormarker-p, nil`" -- but I'll see if I can fix Emacs.app

Comment: @CharlesStewart, it's something.  Now I just get a do-not-enter sign.

Comment: @CharlesStewart Post your answer so I can mark it; I've found a hacky fix and I'll add it in an edit.

Comment: Perhaps [this link to Vincent Goulet port](https://svn.fsg.ulaval.ca/svn-pub/vgoulet/emacs-modified/macos/tags/Emacs-24.2-modified-7/fixpath.el) could help. Besides, there is the excellent [Yamamoto Mitsuharu port](https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port). When I switched to it, I dropped the `fixpath` stuff linked to above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be something related to the complicated way that looking for binaries works in Emacs.  It is possible that each of the following will give a different list of bin directories:

1. `H-v exec-path RET` (the "internal" path that is derived from PATH at the time Emacs initialises) (this is where PDF2DSC looks for `gs`)
2. `M-x eshell RET` followed by `echo $PATH` (set to the init PATH, with possible some additional bin directories inserted; `eshell` is a program that is a bit like UNIX shell, but is implemented in Emacs Lisp)
3. `M-x shell RET` followed by `echo $PATH`, which runs a subordinate shell process, which may have additional bin directories inserted when it runs the `.shrc` file

Auctex path search is tricky, because it looks for executables in either of two ways, using `TeX-run-command` directly, which depends on `exec-path`, and by a invoking subordinate shell, which will depend on the value of `PATH` within that process.  Additionally, when running Aquamacs, the application is launched directly using OSX's `launchd` services, and so the PATH Emacs starts with is independent of the PATH you see at the command line, since the program was not called from any shell.

Adding the gv bin directory to `exec-path` might help, or try using a distribution such as Texlive, which has a single bin directory containing both `gs` and the `pdftex`, etc., executables.

---

#### vermiculus' bounty award notice

After checking those directories and applying fixes as necessary, `gs` should start working properly.  If after you apply these fixes and a 'Do-Not-Enter' sign appears where images should be, follow:

1. Do one of the following:

   - `.emacs`
     Evaluate `(setq preview-gs-options '("-q" "-dNOSAFER" "-dNOPAUSE" "-DNOPLATFONTS" "-dPrinted" "-dTextAlphaBits=4" "-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4"))`, tailoring to your setup.  The important bit is changing `"-dSAFER"` to `"-dNOSAFER"`.
   - (GUI)

     1. Preview -> Customize -> Extend this menu
     2. Preview -> Customize -> Customize GS...
     3. Change option `"-dSAFER"` to `"-dNOSAFER"` (I'm unsure of what this does, but it worked.)
2. Remove previews from the document and re-preview.

As mentioned in the comments, changing this option may be dangerous if you are working with documents that you don't trust; otherwise it is almost certainly safe.

Comment: Using  `gs` with the `-dNOSAFER` option is potentially dangerous!

Comment: So I figured -- what exactly does this do? is there a better way?

Comment: @vermiculus: -dSAFER stops gs from doing certain things, most importantly from piping into shell commands.  -dNOSAFER is the default; I'm surprised the option was set to -dSAFER given what preview-latex needs gs to do.  It is almost certainly safe if you are only using preview-latex on files you are familiar with.

Comment: It's certainly worth mentioning in the answer, so I'm glad you brought it up.  Thankfully, I primarily use TeX (at the moment) to do my own homework.  Do you know of a better way to go about this, or perhaps the dangers of using `-dNOSAFER`?