# Can't get AUCTeX to do a preview

Tags: emacs, auctex

I'm running Arch Linux, latest version of Emacs, and trying to get a preview of the document using `c-c c-p c-p` or any that will do a preview after `c-c c-p ...` and just can't get the thing to preview. I keep getting and error message that

> error in process sentinenl: no image was found

or something to that effect. I even tried getting around this but going for `M-X preview-buffer` but I still get the same error.

This is very strange to me, I saw some issues perhaps relating to Ghostscript, but I have 9.10 already installed so I don't see the problem.

Ideas?

Comment: I've had this same problem before.  Does [my earlier question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83970/auctex-preview-latex-and-ghostscript-emacs) help you at all? At any rate, can you tell us what `M-x preview-report-bug` reports?

Comment: In [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.auctex.general/5035) turned out that Ghostscript 9.09 broke `pdf2dsc`.  If you get the same error messages reported there, try downgrading to Ghostscript 9.05, if you can.